# different result when use is not null

Tags: sql-server

when I am using this query:

```
SELECT * from  [dbo].[CRA] 
where [gender] like 'null'
      and [house] like 'null'
      and [residenttime] is  null
      and [worktime] is null
      and [loaiDN] like 'null'
      and [depend] like 'null'
      and [expGD] like 'null'
      and [Grincome] like 'null'
      and [dunocacTCTD] like 'null'
      and [tinhtrangno] like 'null'
      and [tgQHTD] like 'null'
      and [soduTB] like 'null'
      and [TlquaMB] like 'null'
```

result: 81 rows

but when using this query:

```
SELECT * from  [dbo].[CRA] 
where [gender] not like 'null'
      and [house] not like 'null'
      and [residenttime] is not null
      and [worktime] is not null
      and [loaiDN] not like 'null'
      and [depend] not like 'null'
      and [expGD] not like 'null'
      and [Grincome] not like 'null'
      and [dunocacTCTD] not like 'null'
      and [tinhtrangno] not like 'null'
      and [tgQHTD] not like 'null'
      and [soduTB] not like 'null'
      and [TlquaMB] not like 'null'
```

The number of row removed is > 1000 rows

Why the two result are different?

Comment: do you know boolean algebra?

Comment: Why are you using the LIKE operator without wildcards? May as well use equals and not equals. Also 'null' is a string not the NULL value. You have to use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` to check for NULL as equals and not equals will always return false.

Comment: its cus only two of the variable actually have no value in excel file, other variables have "null" filled in, so I have to use different command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `!(A and B) = !A or !B` as per [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

Opposite will be

```
SELECT * from  [dbo].[CRA] 
where [gender] not like 'null'
      or [house] not like 'null'
      or [residenttime] is not null
      or [worktime] is not null
      or [loaiDN] not like 'null'
      or [depend] not like 'null'
      or [expGD] not like 'null'
      or [Grincome] not like 'null'
      or [dunocacTCTD] not like 'null'
      or [tinhtrangno] not like 'null'
      or [tgQHTD] not like 'null'
      or [soduTB] not like 'null'
      or [TlquaMB] not like 'null'
```

or simply,

```
SELECT * from  [dbo].[CRA] 
where not ([gender] like 'null'
      and [house] like 'null'
      and [residenttime] is  null
      and [worktime] is null
      and [loaiDN] like 'null'
      and [depend] like 'null'
      and [expGD] like 'null'
      and [Grincome] like 'null'
      and [dunocacTCTD] like 'null'
      and [tinhtrangno] like 'null'
      and [tgQHTD] like 'null'
      and [soduTB] like 'null'
      and [TlquaMB] like 'null');
```

Comment: Its make sense but my goal is to remove all records that have NULL values for all variables. And only two of the variable actually have no value in excel file, other variables have "null" filled in, so I have to use different commands

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are comparing to a string with your lines such as

```
and [house] not like 'null'
```

Instead leave the quotations off and use is null or not null

```
where Field is null
where Field is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another sample:

```
    SELECT * from  [dbo].[CRA] 
    where COALESCE( NULLIF([gender],'null')
                   ,NULLIF([house],'null')
                   ,[residenttime]
                   ,[worktime]
                   ,NULLIF([loaiDN],'null')
                   ,NULLIF([depend],'null')
                   ,NULLIF([expGD],'null')
                   ,NULLIF([Grincome],'null')
                   ,NULLIF([dunocacTCTD],'null')
                   ,NULLIF([tinhtrangno],'null')
                   ,NULLIF([tgQHTD],'null')
                   ,NULLIF([soduTB],'null')
                   ,NULLIF([TlquaMB],'null')
                   ) IS NULL --Will be returned only all the values is null or 'null'
```

**BUT**

```
           where COALESCE( NULLIF([gender],'null')
           ,NULLIF([house],'null')
           ,[residenttime]
           ,[worktime]
           ,NULLIF([loaiDN],'null')
           ,NULLIF([depend],'null')
           ,NULLIF([expGD],'null')
           ,NULLIF([Grincome],'null')
           ,NULLIF([dunocacTCTD],'null')
           ,NULLIF([tinhtrangno],'null')
           ,NULLIF([tgQHTD],'null')
           ,NULLIF([soduTB],'null')
           ,NULLIF([TlquaMB],'null')
           ) IS NOT NULL --It will be returned at least on value is not null('null')
```